# Three dice are thrown together. What is the probability that exactly two of them show the same face?

Tags: probability

> Three dice are thrown together. What is the probability that exactly two of them show the same face?

I can get anything over first die...so sure event thus probability $1$.
Now in second have to get the very same number as of I got over the first die...so the probability would then be $\frac{1}{6}$ and then in the third one I have to get a number other than that on the first (...which is also same as second)..thus the probability then would be $\frac{5}{6}$.
Thus, total probability would be $\frac{5}{36}$ for one case ...but we have such $^3C_2 = 3$ cases...
Thus, total probability now would be $=3.\frac{5}{36}=\frac{5}{12}$

So is my answer and arguments made right...?
If not please comment on my approach.

Comment: exactly two or at least two?

Comment: Here exactly 2.

Comment: Then your result is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first count how many ways are there for there to be at least $2$ of the same face, and then how many ways for $3$ of the same face.

For the first, we use complementary counting, as we can count the number of cases when all three dice show different values. This can happen in $_6P_3=6\cdot5\cdot4=120$ ways. So, the final result is $6^3-120=96$.

For the second, there are clearly only $6$ ways this can happen.

So, the final number of possibilities is $96-6=90$. We divide by the total number of possibilities, which is $216$, to get $$\frac5{12}$$

Hence, your answer is correct. I've just provided an alternate approach.

Comment: Okay thank you, but can you plz comment over my approach to solve the problem...is it right...or wrong

Comment: Your approach is also correct. I just like mine slightly better, since it is a tad bit more general.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer